# React native Maps, Recentering on a scrollview card by tapping on a marker

Tags: react-native, animation

Hi I am trying to do the opposite of this tutorial, https://codedaily.io/tutorials/9/Build-a-Map-with-Custom-Animated-Markers-and-Region-Focus-when-Content-is-Scrolled-in-React-Native
Where by clicking on the marker it will recenter to the specified image
However i am clueless on what parameters i should be looking out for, and where i can start.

Your opinion and advice would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: I recommend first: following the tutorial and creating your own version of what it is teaching. From there, you can start making modifications to the code, and share what you try with the community here so that we can better assist you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have managed to work this out, just by calling the markers value through the native events to set the point, along with standardizing the card size to the screens width and using scrollTo with animated true.

Comment: Hi, @obumoon the method is as follows `this.myRef.getNode().scrollTo({ x: markerID * (CARD_WIDTH - 5) , animated: true});` 1) so you would be using the ref of the scrollTo method. 2) Next look for the markers ID through the native event 3) I standardize the card sizes so it would go to the correct card